# Formalizing the leading coefficient of $P(2x+1)-2P(x)$

Tags: polynomials

Let's assume that $P(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is a polynomial whose leading coefficient is $1$. How can we find the leading coefficient of the polynomial $P(2x+1)-2P(x)$?

If $P(x) = \sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\alpha_i x^{i}$, then $$\begin{align}P(2x+1) = \sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\alpha_i(2x+1)^{i} &= \sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\alpha_i\biggr(\sum_{0\leq j\leq i}\frac{i!}{(i-j)!j!}2^{i-j}x^{i-j}\biggr)\\ &= \sum_{0\leq i\leq n}\sum_{0\leq j\leq i}\biggr(\frac{i!}{(i-j)!j!}\alpha_i 2^{i-j}\biggr)x^{i-j}\end{align}$$

Then for $i = n$, and $j = 0$, our leading coefficient is $\frac{n!}{n!}\alpha_{n}2^{n} = \alpha_{n}2^n$. Using this fact, we conclude that the leading-coefficient of the polynomial $P(2x+1)-2P(x)$ is $\alpha_n 2^n-2\alpha_n$.

But I am not really sure.

Comment: I would have thought you only cared about the coefficient of $x^n$, at least when $n>1$

Comment: Yes, I still do.

Comment: What do you mean by "formalize"? Do you just mean to find it? Note that unless $P$ is linear, or constant, you only have to look at the leading coefficient of $P$, which makes your computation much easier -- you don't need the majority of it.

Comment: With your edit, you have said that $P(2x+1)= \alpha_n2^n x^n + \cdots$.  Note the question says $\alpha_n=1$. You now have to subtract $2P(x)$

Comment: Yes, I'm happy I've found the correct coefficient in an algebraic way, although it wasn't really necessary.

Comment: Your $\alpha_n 2^n-2$ should be $\alpha_n 2^n-2\alpha_n$ in general, though here $\alpha_n=1$

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The leading coefficient of $P(2x+1)-2P(x)$ is equal to $2^n-2$, where $n={\rm deg}(P)$ when $n>1$. Recall that $P$ is a monic polynomial. Your computation shows that $P(2x+1)=2^nx^n\cdots $ and $2P(x)=2x^n+\cdots $.

For a monic polynomial $P(x)=x+a$ we have $P(2x+1)-2P(x)=2x+1-a-2(x+a)=1-a$.

Comment: And with $P(x)=1$ you get $P(2x+1)-2P(x)=-1$ which fits your first expression